# Elasticsearch with node.js how to make unique field when insert document to an index

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm developing search engine to my project and i'm using `Elasticsearch` and `node.js` for the server.

Every night I have a parser that scrap data from some website and insert it to the db.
For now it duplicates the data that I already have.

Can I make a unique field inside the index when insert a document for example `title : {unique : true}` and by that it will not insert me a document that come with this title

Here is my code :

```
async function insertManual(manual) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const result = await client.index({
        index : 'completeindexthree',
        body : {
            brand : manual.brand,
            category : manual.category,
            url : manual.url,
            title : manual.title, // example {unique : true}
            parsingData : new Date().toString()
        }
    })
    await client.indices.refresh({index: 'completeindexthree'})
    resolve(result);
  })
}
```

the second is , how can i delete all my duplicates that already got in by title from that index in node.js not from logstach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

Yes it is possible, not by using the `unique` keyword though.
According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html), if you set an `_id` and this id exist already it will be replaced/overwrite

> If the target is an index and the document already exists, the request updates the document and increments its version.

Furthermore you [will find this section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-desc)

> Using _create guarantees that the document is only indexed if it does not already exist.

## To fix

You should set an `_id` per document and use the [create](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_create)

Your code may look like the following:

```js
async function insertManual(manual) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const result = await client.create({
        index : 'completeindexthree',
        id: manual.id,   // <- Here is your unique id.
        body : {
            brand : manual.brand,
            category : manual.category,
            url : manual.url,
            title : manual.title, // example {unique : true}
            parsingData : new Date().toString()
        }
    })
    await client.indices.refresh({index: 'completeindexthree'})
    resolve(result);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't give an id, elastic search creates a unique id, if you do, it creates the id you gave.**

payload should be like this

```json
{
 id:"you_unique_id",
 body:{foo,"bar"}

}
```